# How to install Drupal 8 with an existing database?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I'd like to make an install of Drupal 8 with an existing database of a previous installation, using the CLI (to be able to automatise the process, in my case when building a Docker container).

So, I first execute `composer` but then I need another command to configure the installation with my existing database.

I noticed that `drush` has a [site-install](https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/site/site:install/) command that takes options related to the database, but I tested it and this is only to set the database details and create a new database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Drupal Console we can now use the [new option](https://github.com/hechoendrupal/drupal-console/pull/4143) `--default` to automatically set the default database details in the *settings.php* file:

```
drupal database:add \
  --database=DATABASE \
  --username=USERNAME \
  --password=PASSWORD \
  --default
```

Since the `hash_salt` variable has also to be set in the *settings.php* file, like in a manual installation, we need to do it using `drush`:

```
drush php:eval '
  include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . "/core/includes/install.inc";
  $settings["settings"]["hash_salt"] = (object) [
    "value"    => \Drupal\Component\Utility\Crypt::randomBytesBase64(55),
    "required" => true,
  ];
  drupal_rewrite_settings($settings);
'
```

Answer (score 0):

Recommended way to install and maintain Drupal 8 website is with composer:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-and-manage-dependencies#download-core

Then you'll have to add all the modules you used before - also use composer to install them.

Then simply import your old database over the new one (if you prefer console mysql command will do the trick, but drush is also valid option).